# Неправильно сравниваются значения в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю простую проверку на ширину экрана для адаптации, но получается что-то не то, вот код:

```
    var width = +$(window).width();
    alert(width); //нормально выводит значение ширины окна
    if (width < 1024) { //не срабатывает в любом случае
        $('.fixed-1').css("position", "relative");
    }
    else{
        alert(width < 1024); //выводит всегда false
        var width_true = $('#menu2').width();
        $('.fixed-l').css("max-width", width_true);
        $('.fixed-l').css(" position", "fixed");
    }
```

Даже когда окно меньше 1024 пикселей - возвращает `false`. В чем дело?

Comment: var width = +$(window).width(); а зачем вы пставили знаки = + ?

Comment: @Арсен без + тоже не работает

Comment: а вы как проверяете? ресайзом?

Comment: Ваш код будет работать только при перезагрузке страницы

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас `alert(width < 1024);` запускается при условии, если `width>=1024`, поэтому условие всегда будет `false`. Ошибка не в коде, а в логике.

Comment: @Арсен этот код в setInterval

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin этот алерт срабатывает всегда, и когда меньше 1024 и когда больше

Comment: @humster_spb я поставил в setInterval

Comment: @shumik_UA, все равно не понимаю логику: смотрим на ширину `if (width<1024)`, то делаем какие-то манипуляции. Если нет, то идем в ветку `else` и мы точно знаем, что `width>=1024`, а после выводим `alert(width<1024)`, то есть всегда будет выводиться false, как только мы попадаем в эту ветку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все должно работать. Вероятно, проблема в вашем таймере.
Используйте вместо таймера события:

```js
$(window).on('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  $(window).on('resize', onResize); 
  onResize(); 
});

function onResize() {
  var width = $(window).width(), 
      test = $('#test'); 
  if (width < 1024)
    test.css('color', 'red');
  else
    test.css('color', 'green');
  test.text('Ширина вьюпорта: ' + width); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

**[Демо на JSbin](http://jsbin.com/zetopavudi/edit?js,output)**

Comment: $(window).on('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    setInterval(function(){
     var width_true = $('#menu2').width();
     $('.fixed-l').css("max-width", width_true);
    }, 200);
   $(window).on('resize', onResize); 
   onResize(); 
 });

 function onResize() {
   var width = $(window).width(), 
     test = $('.fixed-1'); 
   if (width < 1024)
    test.css('position', 'relative');
   else
    test.css('position', 'fixed');
}
та же проблема, работает только else

Comment: http://shumikua.zzz.com.ua/lottery.php вот, скрипт над div.menu-1

Comment: @shumik_UA, ну и что это за ужас в комменте? Вот ваша страничка с вырезанными скриптами и добавлением только одного в начало `body`: http://jsbin.com/qeqaqicapa/edit?html,output (Подвигайте разделитель между разметкой и выводом)

Comment: @shumik_UA, в целом не совсем понимаю, чего Вы хотите добиться на той странице (с мобилки читать такую разметку неудобно), поэтому добавил дивижн в конце бади - с тем же классом, и изменением фонового цвета как в примере: http://jsbin.com/xacocumaga/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Оберните ваш код в обработчик события

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = +$(window).width();
    alert(width); 
    if (width < 1024) { 
    $('.fixed-1').css("position", "relative");
    } else {
        alert(width < 1024); 
        var width_true = $('#menu2').width();
        $('.fixed-l').css("max-width", width_true);
        $('.fixed-l').css(" position", "fixed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Логика почти рабочая, а что если пользователь не ресайзит окно ?

Comment: у меня стоит setInterval, проблема в if

Comment: @Арсен На этот случай вообще надо бы прописать всякие \@media (max-width: 1024px)

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис причём тут "всякие @media" ? я о том вам написал что в JS у вас должно быть две логики, первая работает при загрузке DOM а  второй, при ресайзе.